# raphaeljs Inverted X Coordinate

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael

I want to make scrolling animation, where some of the object is animated using transform(flipping horizontal) method. 
My code is:

```
obj.attr('transform', 's-1,1');
```

But it seems when I try to scroll when the animation flipping, the coordinate x got inverted.
Here's the code to scrolling when I press prev button:

```
button.hover(function(){
  var el_x = obj.attr('x');
  obj.attr('x', el_x-1);
});
```

Is there some way to not inverted x coordinate when I'm flipping?
Please, I desperately need your help

Comment: You should create a minimal [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) exposing the problem so people can play with it, understand the issue and suggest alternatives or solutions.